Understanding this use of かける
While I was looking for explanations about the proverb 敵もさるもの引っ搔くもの, I encountered the below sentences involving a particular use of 掛ける:
1.『さる』を『猿(さる)』とかけたしゃれ。
2.「さるもの」は「然る者（さすがな者の意）」のことで、この「然る（さる）」と引っ掻く「猿（さる）」を掛けて続けたしゃれ。
3.『さるもの』は『然る者』、つまり『さすがな者』という意味で、その『さる』に動物の『猿』が引っ掻くというとかけているんだそうです。
I think it corresponds to this definition from Meikyou:

同音・類字音を利用して、一つの語句にもう一つ別の意味を持たせる。掛詞(かけことば)にする。「『秋風ぞ立つ』の『秋』に『飽き』を━」「『うぢ山』の『うぢ』を『憂し』に━」

However, it is still not clear to me how particles を, に and と work with this 掛ける. Is this と quotative? Does AをBにCとかける mean something like "play A on B resulting in C"?

In this sense, AをBと掛ける and AをBに掛ける are used interchangeably. This と is "with", the same と as in 彼と友達になる or たくさんの鍵を鍵穴と組み合わせる. AとBを掛ける is also almost the same, but in this word order, the と is usually taken as "and". "To play A on B resulting in C" would be AをB(と/に)掛けてC(と/に)する (for example, ポテトにトマトを掛けてポマトにする).
However, AにBと掛ける is wrong; "その『さる』に動物の『猿』が引っ掻くというとかけている" seems unnatural to me.
